# Password problems in 19.10

Tags: permissions, sudo, password

So, basically I have a really weird problem right now with my passwords here in Ubuntu.

I removed my password from this user via /sudoers
Granted root privileges to all users, following the manuals.

And everything is okay. The terminal doesn't ask anything now, even when I use sudo su for example.

But... the Ubuntu Software is now asking for a password, when I want to install something. And the problem is, that the old password now isn't correct. I've tried many of them, even the empty one. Nothing.

What a hell is this ? Please :(

Comment: Please share the documentation you were following.

Comment: # User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
Antonio  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

Comment: Could you please post the content of `/etc/passwd` and everything in `/etc/sudoers.d`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZNH3H7UL @StrabagISS_Krall please help me :(